# Gps Coordinate 1 mile away - Haversine

Tags: trigonometry, spherical-trigonometry

I've come across the need for doing GPS calculations. I've implemented the haversineformula for gps distances but I need the opposite, a point 1 mile away in any direction. The GPS coordinates are converted into radians ...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

haversine<sup>-1</sup>(h, r) = 2r * arcsin(sqrt(h))
haversine(θ) = sin<sup>2</sup>(θ/2)

d = haversine<sup>-1</sup>(haversine(lat<sub>2</sub> - lat<sub>1</sub>) + cos(lat<sub>1</sub>) * cos(lat<sub>2</sub>) * haversine(lon<sub>2</sub> - lon<sub>1</sub>), 3956)

d = distance in miles between two gps points
lat<sub>1</sub> and lon<sub>1</sub> (known variables)
lat<sub>2</sub> and lon<sub>2</sub> represent the second gps coordinate (unknown variables)

So what I'm asking is for the function ...
gps(d) = .... = { latitude, longitude } where d is a known variable and the first set of coordinates is a known variable.

Comment: If the distance is small and you are not considering terrain, couldn't use just define a circle in (east,north) coordinates and then convert that to (lat,lon)? That might not be the mathematical answer you are hoping for, but you could do it and have it done in the same amount of time it took to post your question.

Comment: Suppose I use the unit circle, how would the conversions work?

Comment: Two steps. First you go from ENU to ECEF, and then from ECEF to WGS-84 (which I believe is what GPS uses). Details for each of the conversions can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_datum#Local_east.2C_north.2C_up_.28ENU.29_coordinates).